# How many different names can be created by using the letters...?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the name: AABBC DEF ACK

I want to find how many different name combinations with 3 words I can come up with. I know there exists $\frac{11!}{3!2!2!}$ different permutations. But, what is the best way to partition these into three words. (Words must be at least 2 words length it is the only rule.)

My attempt:

I have three spaces and 3 different partitions can be obtained:

```
                      _ _ _
                      2 2 7
                      2 3 6
                      2 4 5
```

Result = $\frac{11!}{3!2!2!}$$*$[$\binom{11}{2}$$\binom{9}{2}$$\binom{7}{2}$$*$$\frac{3!}{2!}$$+$$\binom{11}{2}$$\binom{9}{3}$$\binom{6}{6}$$*$$3!$$+$$\binom{11}{2}$$\binom{9}{4}$$\binom{5}{5}$$*$$3!$$]$

Is this answer true and is it the best way to solve this problem?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First, find out all permutations of those letters, i.e. all 11-letter word.

Then, you need to add three spaces between those letters. The rule means that the first space must not be in the first position, there must be two letters between the two consecutive spaces and the last space can be after the 11 letters.

It should not be hard if you think of the question in this way.

You can think of the partitions in this way. Consider all letters are the same, say T. Then, combine two T's with each space. Then, find the permutations of the rest T's and the combined blocks. That will be the number of partitions you can make.

Comment: You are right. Somehow I thought I needed to use all the letters. So according to your remark, for example in this question, after fixing 2 letters for each words, I will have 5 letters left. Then I need to partition those letters. I may or may not use all of them. But what I could not figure out is how to eliminate the same permutations. I have letters occuring more than once, simplest solution seems to be fixing the letters occurring only once like AB | CD | EF and then partitioning the left letters. But is it right? I do not feel comfortable.

Comment: Also if I had to use all the letters, then could I think this question as a stars&bars question right? (I have 11 stars and 2 bars (since I have 3 words) so the result would be equal to $\frac{11!}{3!2!2!}$$\binom{11+3-1}{3-1}$ )

Comment: There will be no repetitions. As the order of the 11 letters are fixed in the first place. What you do is inserting spaces according to the rules. Your answer should be modified because there are acturally 5 stars and 2 bars. Because 4 stars are combined with 2 bars already in order to satisfy the rules and the last two stars are fixed, no bars can be inserted in.